# Clear data from table which has no header

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating class for working with tables. One of the command is to delete all data from table for which I use cTable.DataBodyRange.ClearContents. It works fine when the table has header, but without header this command remove the whole table. Any idea how to remove data but keep the table?

Comment: Going to need a lot more details than that.

Comment: What concretely?